# Не работает перемотка в Video js, и видео не воспроизводится пока полностью не загрузится

Tags: html, reactjs, видео

Не работает перемотка `Video js`
А также если видео длинное (много весит), его нельзя воспроизвести до тех пор, пока оно не скачается полностью

Как пофиксить?

П.С. сервер отдаёт видео файлом, то есть, если перейти по ссылке на это видео, оно начинает скачиваться, а не воспроизводиться во вкладке

---

UPD. так же прошу объяснить по поводу типа

```
sources: [{
  src: '//path/to/video.mp4',
  type: 'video/mp4'
}]
```

Когда динамически подставляю тип такой же как расширение файла *(например mov)*
Видео не воспроизводится. Но если тип оставляю стандартный `mp4` то воспроизводится

Answer (score -1):

Для начала про расширение. Потому что MIME тип у mov формата это `video/quicktime`, а mp4 - `video/mp4`. Это указывается в заголовке `Content-Type` HTTP запроса/ответа и указывается тегу `<video></video>`. Вам нужно убедиться что все укзано верно.

Для того чтобы запустить проигрыватель в документации videojs.com описан следующий HTML

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.11.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
  <!-- <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>
  <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
    data-setup="{}"
    playsinline>
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.11.4/video.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Соответственно нужно заменить `MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg` и `MY_VIDEO.mp4`.

P.S. Я знаю что пример из документации работает, потому что использовал его, когда настраивал воспроизведение потокового видео